# Attempted to Recreate Rails model, migrations messed up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, migration, rake

I had a rails Model `List`.

I typed `rails d model list` in my terminal, resulting in this:

```
  invoke  active_record
  remove    db/migrate/20140116161958_create__lists.rb
  remove    app/models/list.rb
  invoke    rspec
  remove      spec/models/list_spec.rb
```

Then I typed `rails g model list name:string size:integer` which gave me this:

```
  invoke  active_record
  create    db/migrate/20140213155321_create_lists.rb
  create    app/models/list.rb
  invoke    rspec
  create      spec/models/list_spec.rb
```

Now, running `rake db:migrate` gives me this:

```
==  CreateLists: migrating ===============================================
-- create_table(:lists)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::DuplicateTable: ERROR:  relation "lists" already exists
```

The issue is that my table was not deleted from my DB. I can't roll back the migration that created that table, because it was destroyed when i ran `rails d model list`.

I could create a new migration and drop the table, but it would be placed after my migration created when I ran `rails g model list...`, so I assume it would error too.

Is my only choice to delete the model again, create a migration to drop the table, then recreate the model?

Also, in the future, how should one go about deleting and recreating a model? Roll back the migration prior to `rails d model`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1>**

before running `rails d model list`

run

```
$ rake db:migrate:down VERSION=20140116161958
```

will roll back the list file to remove table lists from database.

**2>**

but since u have already destroyed your model what u can do is delete table lists from rails database console. try this

```
$ rails dbconsole # from your app root path
```

and then type `drop table lists;`

**3>**

you can drop your table from rails console also

```
$rails console
```

Then just type:

```
ActiveRecord::Migration.drop_table(:lists)
```

**4>**

also u can create a migration file to drop your table :

```
$ rails generate migration DropListsTable
```

this will create an empty migration file now edit that file to look like:

```
class DropListsTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    drop_table :lists
  end

  def down
    raise ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration
  end
end
```

then run `$ rake db:migrate`